# can i use iMac (Retina 5k, 27-inch, Late 2015) as target monitor?

Tags: imac, target-display

i have an iMac 2020 and a late 2015 iMac. I wish to know if it’s possible to use the latter as target display monitor. and if yes, which cable should i buy? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2014 iMacs were the last to support target display mode as these were before the 5K screens were introduced, which requires too much bandwidth.

> - 27-inch iMac models introduced in 2009 and 2010: Use a Mini DisplayPort cable […]
> - All iMac models introduced in 2011, 2012, 2013 and mid 2014: Use a Thunderbolt cable […]

Furthermore, your 2020 iMac is too new to support target display mode even if you had a ≤2014 iMac to use as a display.

> You can connect any of these older iMac models to another Mac from 2019 or earlier

[Use your iMac as a display with target display mode - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204592)